# pstricks won't even start in new TeX installation - Plain TeX

Tags: pstricks, plain-tex

Did a clean install via TeX-Live 2022 onto a new mac. None of my old TeX files would compile. Reduced to the following and still won't compile.

Plain TeX using TeXShop, TeX+DVI.

---

```
\input pstricks

\input pst-plot

\noindent Hello, World!

\bye
```

---

Complains about an undefined control sequence \colorlet that seems to be used when pst-plot loads pstricks-add. It will compile if I don't input pst-plot.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You should raise with pstricks but this is possibly a solution

```
\input pstricks

% rough approximation
\def\colorlet#1[#2]#3{%
\expandafter\let\csname\string\color@#1\expandafter\endcsname\csname\string\color@#3\endcsname
\message{defining color #1: \expandafter\meaning\csname\string\color@#1\endcsname}%
}

\input pst-plot

\noindent Hello, World!

\bye
```

it logs

```
defining color tempcolor: macro:->0. setgray
defining color tempcolor: macro:->1. setgray
```

Comment: this works with etex (get unrelated errors from classic tex)

Comment: That works with the minimal test and with at least one other file.

Comment: Thanks! Will check with pstricks as you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

if you do not need `pstricks-add`:

```
\input pstricks
\let\PSTricksAddLoaded\endinput
\input pst-plot

\noindent Hello, World!

\bye
```

However, it will be fixed in an update of PSTricks (next few days)